# Excel vba variable logic operator

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where the user can define some rules, but I'm struggling with getting the log to work. I want difference results based on what the user wants, but ideally I want to stay away from have to but multiple select cases in or if lines.

What I have Is this (Simplified - It's in a loop so the values will change for every row - I'm just using an example):

The operator can vary, it could be ">","=>" etc.

```
Field1Value = "Football"
Operator1 = "="
Rule1 = "Football"

If Evaluate(Field1Value & Operator1 & Rule1 ) Then

'Run My Code

End If
```

So in the above example the logic would be true and my code would run, but I'm getting a type mismatch error.

Has anyone any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

********UPDATE********

Here's the full Code:

```
Workbooks(MasterWB).Activate

Sheets("Rules").Select

    NoRules = Sheets("Rules").Range("J6").End(xlDown).Row

    For a = 7 To NoRules

        Field1 = Workbooks(DataWB).Sheets(DataWS).Rows(1).Find(Workbooks(MasterWB).Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 10), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column
        Operator1 = Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 11)
        Rule1 = Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 12)

        Operator = Sheets("Rules").Range("J5").Cells(a, 13)

        Field2 = Workbooks(DataWB).Sheets(DataWS).Rows(1).Find(Workbooks(MasterWB).Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 14), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column
        Operator2 = Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 15)
        Rule2 = Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 16)

        HighlightColumn = Workbooks(DataWB).Sheets(DataWS).Rows(1).Find(Workbooks(MasterWB).Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 17), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column
        HighlightColour = Workbooks(MasterWB).Sheets("Rules").Cells(a, 17).Interior.ColorIndex

        Workbooks(DataWB).Activate

        With Workbooks(DataWB).Sheets(DataWS)

            .Select

            Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

            For b = 2 To Lastrow

            Field1Value = .Cells(b, Field1).Value

                If Evaluate(Field1Value & Operator1 & Rule1) Then

                        .Cells(b, HighlightColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = HighlightColour                      

                End If

            Next b

        End With


    Next a
```

Comment: Can you supply your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
Field1Value = "Football"
Operator1 = "="
Rule1 = "Football"

Dim x As Variant

strEvaluate = Chr(34) & Field1Value & Chr(34) & Operator1 & Chr(34) & Rule1 & Chr(34)

x = Evaluate("IF(" & strEvaluate & ",1,0)")

if x = 1 then
'Run your code
end if
```

Or instead of `1` and `0` use `TRUE` and `FALSE`. My language is not English. But I think this works also.

```
x = Evaluate("IF(" & strEvaluate & "," & True & ", " & False & ")")

if x = TRUE then
'Run your code
end if
```

Comment: Perfect! This got it! Thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 3):

Hold on I don't mean to steal Credit from FreeMan but following worked for me:

```
Sub test()
Dim Field1Value As String
Dim Operator1 As String
Dim Rule1 As String

Dim test As Range
Dim Passed As Boolean

    Field1Value = "Football"
    Operator1 = "="
    Rule1 = "Football"

    Passed = Evaluate("=" & """" & Field1Value & """" & Operator1 & """" & Rule1 & """")

    'Different way of achievieng same thing ignore this if you want to 
    Set test = Range("A1")
    test.Formula = "=" & """" & Field1Value & """" & Operator1 & """" & Rule1 & """"
    Passed = test.Value

    MsgBox Passed
End Sub
```

I tried it a with several values and operator and it works fine.

So I would only correct FreeMan by adding `"=" &` as first part of Evaluate.

So to make this more concise I'm saying write this :

```
Evaluate("=" & """" & Field1Value & """" & Operator1 & """" & Rule1 & """")
```

Comment: Yup, that makes sense to me. I missed the leading `=`.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Assuming that you're expecting "Football" = "Football" yields `True`, then give this a try:</strike>

```
If Evaluate("""" & Field1Value & """ " & Operator1 & " """ & Rule1 & """") Then
```

Note, I enclosed my strings in quotes - you need to pass those to `Evaluate()`

Actually, according to my reading of the MS Docs, I don't think this will work.

Evaluate(*Name*)

> *Name*: A formula or the name of the object, using the naming convention of Microsoft Excel. The length of the name must be less than or equal to 255 characters.

What is the definition of "Football"? Is it a simple text string? My reading indicates that `Evaluate()` will execute a built in function or a UDF, but not a simple comparison.

Comment: Evaluate only accepts literals according to your answer? That's false, mate.